# How to hide a toplevel GTK window while executing its callback

Tags: c++, c, gtk, boost-thread

I have a GTK application with a top level window named `main_window` and a button labeled `Update`. When `Update` is clicked, a callback is executed. Within the callback, I'd like to hide the main_window and start a new thread to do some really long processing. The problem is that when I use gtk_widget_hide(), "main_window" gets unmapped (I think), and the callback stops executing. Here is my callback:

```
void update_button_clicked (GtkButton* update, 
            GtkWidget* main_window)
{
    int retval = 2;
    gtk_widget_hide (main_window); // Hide the main window
    thread m_thread (bind (&update_thread, &retval));
    int status = retval;
    while (status != 0 && status != 1) {
        gtk_main_iteration();
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock (mut);
        {
           status = retval;
        }
    }
    if (status) // Thread succeeded
    {
        show_succeeded_dialog();
        gtk_main_quit();
    } else { // Thread failed
        show_failed_dialog();
       // Do error handling
    }
}
```

My Thread:

```
void update_thread (int *retval)
{
    int status = do_long_work();  
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock (mut);
    {
        *retval = status;
    }
}
```

Once `main_window` is hidden, the `while` loop in my callback stops executing and the application hangs. However, if I take out the call to `gtk_widget_hide (main_window);` everything works as expected. I'd really like to hide the window because the thread processing takes a long time to complete. Is there any way I can do this with GTK but still have the callback continue executing?

Answer (score 0):

Is it really needed to hide the window? I would do the following: firstly, I'd disable the window by calling `gtk_set_sensitive()`.

Secondly, I would create a `VBox` with two cells. In the first cell I'd put all the widgets you have right now. In the second one, I'd just put just a panel with a label. The panel would be hidden (this way, your widgets will be shown as they are just shown now).

After calling `gtk_set_sensitive()`, I'd hide the panel with your widgets, and show the panel with the label, saying something like "Processing...".

Maybe it is easier to do than to explain it; hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's just that my main window takes up a lot of real estate on the screen, and I thought it might look better hidden while the thread does its processing. Thanks for your suggestion of using a "Processing" label. I thought about just having a dialog with a progress bar, but I thought it might be better aesthetically to just let my app crunch numbers in the background and only notify the user when it's finished which was why I wanted to hide everything. But I'm not sure if that's possible, so I may have to go the progress bar route in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's most certainly not true that your callback stops executing when the window is hidden. There must be something else going wrong. Have you read all the [requisite information](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness) about using threads with GTK?

Answer (score 0):

try gtk_window_move(), different but same effect.

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-move

Comment: this link is broken